# sqlalchemy: get rows affected by bulk delete

Tags: python, events, sqlalchemy

I need to get all rows that were affected by a bulk delete like that:

```
Session.query(SomeClass).filter_by(foo='bar').delete()
```

I found [the possibility to subscribe to bulk delete events](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_bulk_delete) but can't figure out how I can use this event to actually get the information I need.

Comment: You could start by making a small testcase script.. Something like this: http://plaes.org/files/2012-Q1/sqlalchemy-after-insert.py

Comment: What is the context? Why would you like to have those rows? Do you need all rows or just `ID`s. Also, if your model has inheritance, the object `SomeClass` might be mapped to rows in multiple tables.

Comment: @van I only need to know the id of the row that got deleted. It's for a lib that i wrote that monitors database object life cycles. With instance based adding/deleting this is easy, because you can hook into events for each object, while on bulk deletion no objects get created which therefore requires a different approach. Regarding your point that `SomeClass` might be mapped to rows in multiple Tables: the Query.delete() command currently does not support bulk deletion against more than one table, which makes things a bit easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, found the answer \☺/ You can re-execute the select statement that was used to select the rows for bulk deletion. Unfortunately you can't query the ORM objects, but you can get a list of all the deleted rows with the old column values as tuples:

```
def after_bulk_delete(session, query, query_context, result):
    affected_table = query_context.statement.froms[0]
    affected_rows = query_context.statement.execute().fetchall() 

sqlalchemy.event.listen(Session, "after_bulk_delete", after_bulk_delete)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question and for being explicit (tuple vs ORM objects). You just saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Do you have this working in a more recent version of SQLAlchemy? I can't get the row data this way with 1.1.5. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

From

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete

> Perform a bulk delete query.
>
> Deletes rows matched by this query from the database.
>
> Returns:  the count of rows matched as returned by the database’s “row
>   count” feature.

Comment: You only get the number of affected rows, not the ids.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are wondering how to get the number of rows, affected by the `delete` statement (and `update` as well) in **SQLAlchemy 2.0** syntax style:

```
    st = delete(Model).where(Model.some_field == some_value)
    res = session.execute(st)
    session.commit()

    print(f"Rows affected: {res.rowcount}")
```

Comment: Seems like it works perfectly fine without the commit here, per my tests.